# Given $M\subset H$ and $\lambda$ a continuous linear functional, show there is a unique linear functional $\Lambda$ on $H$

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $M$ is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$ and $\lambda$ is a continuous linear functional on $M$ with

$$\sup_{m\in M, m\neq 0} {|\lambda(m)|\over \|m\|}=c$$

Using Hilbert space methods, show that there is a unique continuous linear functional $\Lambda$ on $H$ with:

$$\lambda(m)=\Lambda(m)$$

For all $m\in M$ and

$$\sup_{h\in H, h\neq 0} {|\Lambda(h)|\over \|h\|}=c$$

---

So this one is really bothering me... I am thinking something along the lines of,

1) Assume $\lambda (m)=\Lambda(m)$

2) Let $h\in H$ be given... if $h\in M$ then we know $\sup{|\lambda(h)|\over \|h\|}=c$ and so we are done.

3) Let $h\in H$ be given... if $h\notin M$... not really sure where to go from here, or if this is the right approach.

Comment: what you are trying to proof is a version of Hahn-Banach theorem.you can assume the one for smei norms and imply this version.

Comment: Do you know the Riesz representation theorem for continuous linear functionals on Hilbert spaces?

Comment: @DanielFischer so using that, could I say something along these lines?

As $\lambda(m)$ is a linear functional, that means there exists some $g\in M$ such that $\lambda(m)=\langle m, g\rangle , \forall m\in M$. As $M$ is a subset of $H$ this means that that means that $g\in H$... so how would I go about showing that $\lambda(m)=<m,g>=\Lambda(m)$?

Comment: If we index the inner product with the space, then since $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle_M$ is the restriction of $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle_H$, it is clear that $\Lambda\colon x \mapsto \langle x,g\rangle_H$ is an extension of $\lambda \colon m \mapsto \langle m,g\rangle_M$. It remains to see that $\lVert\Lambda\rVert = \lVert\lambda\rVert$, and that $\Lambda$ is the unique extension of $\lambda$ with that property. Orthogonal decomposition helps seeing that.

Comment: So using this idea of restriction/extension, is how we show $\lambda(m)=\Lambda(m)$ correct? What do you mean by $\|\Lambda\|$ and $\|\lambda\|$? Do you mean $|\Lambda |$ and $|\lambda |$?

Comment: The norm of a linear functional is the $\sup$ expression in your question. $\lVert\lambda\rVert$ is however less to type.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks for the help so far. Am I correct about the $\lambda =\Lambda $ being a result of the restriction/extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_{M}$ be the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto $M$. Define $\tilde{\lambda}(x)=\lambda(P_{M}x)$. Then $\tilde{\lambda}$ is a linear functional satisfying
$$
    |\tilde{\lambda}(x)|= |\lambda(P_{M}x)|\le \|\lambda\|\|P_{M}x\|\le \|\lambda\|\|P_{M}\|\|x\| \le \|\lambda\|\|x\|.
$$
So $\|\tilde{\lambda}\|\le\|\lambda\|$. The reverse inequality follows because $\tilde{\lambda}$ extends $\lambda$ and, so, must have at least as large a norm.

**Uniqueness:** Suppose $\Lambda$ is another continuous linear extension of $\lambda$ to $H$ with $\|\Lambda\|_{H}=\|\lambda\|_{M}$. Using the Riesz representation, there is a unique $y\in H$ such that
$$
             \Lambda(x)-\tilde{\lambda}(x)=(x,y).
$$
The left side is $0$ on $M$, which means $y \in M^{\perp}$. And there is a unique $z \in H$ such that $\tilde{\lambda}(x)=(x,z)$. But $\tilde{\lambda}(x)=\tilde{\lambda}(P_{M}x)=(P_{M}x,z)=(x,P_{M}z)$ implies $P_{M}z=z$ by uniqueness. So $\Lambda(x)=(x,z+y)$ with $z\perp y$. Also part of the Riesz Representation is that the norms of the functionals are the norms of the representing vector. So,
$$
     \|\Lambda\|^{2}=\|y+z\|^{2}=\|y\|^{2}+\|z\|^{2}=\|y\|^{2}+\|\tilde{\lambda}\|^{2}.
$$
So $\|\Lambda\|=\|\tilde{\lambda}\|$ forces $y=0$, and, therefore, $\Lambda-\tilde{\lambda}=0$.

Comment: By $\tilde{\lambda}(x)$ do you mean $\Lambda(x)$? Also, how do you get these inequalities: $|\lambda(P_{M}x)|\le \|\lambda\|\|P_{M}x\|\le \|\lambda\|\|P_{M}\|\|x\| \le \|\lambda\|\|x\|$?

Comment: @user3784030 : Oops. Yes, I forgot you wanted to use the name $\Lambda$.

Comment: @user3784030 : $c=\|\lambda\|$, and $\|P_{M}x\|\le \|x\|$ because $P_{M}$ is an orthogonal projection: indeed $x=(x-P_{M}x)+P_{M}x$ is an orthogonal decomposition, which gives $\|x\|^{2}=\|(x-P_{M}x)\|^{2}+\|P_{M}x\|^{2}$, and implies that $\|P_{M}x\|\le \|x\|$, $\|(I-P_{M})x\|\le \|x\|$.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but we know that $\Lambda(m)$ exists because of the Hahn–Banach theorem, correct?

Comment: @user3784020 : I read your questing as asking for the desired functional using Hilbert space techniques. That's why I did it this way. I forgot to show uniqueness. doh! I'm adding that now.

Comment: thank you so far with all of your help with this. If you have a moment, could you also take a look at another question I had posted? (I feel bad as the question is off topic, but there is no way to send a private message). http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937429/how-to-know-if-a-space-has-a-convergent-subsequence